# How to secure service account key for an application that is NOT running on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, service-accounts

I have request from users to  be able to connect to my datasets and table in bigquery to fetch the data and manipulate it programmatically outside of GCP

The situation now that i created a service account with credentials to view data and i share the  json key of this service account with users in email .

1. I want to avoid users to use the key inside their code
2. best way to secure sharing this key with them

Answer (score 2):

The best way to share your application outside Google Cloud is through `Workload Identity Federation`. Although, creating **public/private key pairs** is also a secured way to use and share your user-managed service account, it can still impose a threat and security risk if not correctly managed.

Just run through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) and use IAM external identities to impersonate a service account to avoid any security issues on your security account keys even without mantaining it.

Comment: Hello Poala  thanks for your comment  

does workload identity federation can work with a user local machine using python to extract data from big Query ? which  external identity provider should apply in that  case ?